# save screenshots into local file system in blender game engine in python

Tags: python, game-engine

In blender render, it is ok to render a scene and save the scene image into the local file system with the code shown below

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = '/home/user/Documents/image.jpg'
bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

Now instead of working on the blender render, I am using the blender game engine to create a game, the blender game engine is working for me. but I I don't know how can to script to save the game screenshot into the local file system?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same code but for the game engine:

```
from bge import render

render.makeScreenshot('Screenshot#.png')
```

On Windows 10 you need to run as Admin to be able to save screenshots to the primary disk.

Comment: why On Windows 10 you need to run as Admin to be able to save screenshots to the primary disk.?